# embedded ravendb on OSX (mono)

Tags: .net, macos, mono, ravendb

Building a .NET4 app with RavenDB using Mono 2.10.8. When I try to do anything with an embedded document store on OSX, I get the following exception:

```
System.NotSupportedException: This platform is not supported
  at System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Raven.Database.Util.PortUtil.FindPort () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Raven.Database.Util.PortUtil.GetPort (System.String portStr) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Raven.Database.Config.InMemoryRavenConfiguration.Initialize () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Raven.Database.Config.RavenConfiguration.LoadConfigurationAndInitialize (IEnumerable`1 values) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Raven.Database.Config.RavenConfiguration..ctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Raven.Client.Embedded.EmbeddableDocumentStore.get_Configuration () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

Coming from the first place I try to open the embedded store and use it. I've looked at the source for the Mono implementation of `IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties()` and found:

```
public static IPGlobalProperties GetIPGlobalProperties ()
{
    PlatformID platform = Environment.OSVersion.Platform;
    if (platform != PlatformID.Unix)
    {
        return new Win32IPGlobalProperties();
    }
    if (Directory.Exists ("/proc"))
    {
        MibIPGlobalProperties mibIPGlobalProperties = new MibIPGlobalProperties ("/proc");
        if (File.Exists (mibIPGlobalProperties.StatisticsFile))
        {
            return mibIPGlobalProperties;
        }
    }
    if (Directory.Exists ("/usr/compat/linux/proc"))
    {
        MibIPGlobalProperties mibIPGlobalProperties = new MibIPGlobalProperties ("/usr/compat/linux/proc");
        if (File.Exists (mibIPGlobalProperties.StatisticsFile))
        {
            return mibIPGlobalProperties;
        }
    }
    throw new NotSupportedException ("This platform is not supported");
}
```

Now, I'm still learning the ins and outs of OSX system configuration (I've been a Windows guy my whole life), but I am pretty sure I haven't done anything stupid to my system configuration. Which tells me that either this will *never* work on OSX in the current implementation of Mono, or I've got a big blind spot. The latter seems more likely, so help me out :)

Comment: I think this will help if you're not using the dmcs compiler. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882590/why-are-there-four-mono-c-sharp-compilers

Comment: @kenny I don't see how that would be a factor here, even if it was possible that I could be using something other than DMCS to compile a .NET4 app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you'll explicitly specify a port, you'll be able to move beyond that, the default port is *, which means "find me one that is open". Specify 8080 and see if this helps. Note that we aren't supporting RavenDB Embedded on Mac.
You *can* run the RavenDB client on the Mac, though.

Comment: Ah so embedded is not supported and that is why it is initializing the connection, even though I have not specified a connection.  2 questions - is there a desire to add that support at some point; and is there a reason the EmbeddableDocumentStore does not preemptively throw an unsupported exception on OSX? Thanks!